How to Fix Zig Build Failures Caused by Unexpected Errors
I am using Zig version 0.12.0-dev.1496+bf0387b6bb.
I am encountering an issue while trying to build my Zig project on Windows 10. When I execute the command zig build, I receive multiple warnings and errors related to cached ZIR code and the inability to build certain components.
build proccess fails with the output:-
warning(zcu): unable to write cached ZIR code for D:\zig\lib\compilerbuild_runner.zig to C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\zig\z\9009aebd82eabb57864fb20271ff7d7a: Unexpected
warning(zcu): unable to write cached ZIR code for D:\zig\lib\stdbounded_array.zig to C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\zig\z\5888e4048994427b1bdb443afda1100d: Unexpected
...
error: unable to build compiler_rt: Unexpected
error: unable to build zig's multitarget libc: Unexpected
D:\zig\lib\std\std.zig:98:26: error: unable to load 'D:\zig\lib\std/wasm.zig': Unexpected

I expected the build to complete successfully without any errors, allowing me to run my Zig project.
I tried

I cleared the Zig cache by deleting the contents of C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\zig\z.

I ensured that I have the latest version of Zig installed.

I checked file permissions and ran the terminal as an administrator.

I tried building a simple example project to see if the issue was specific to my project, but It still did not work.


Please tell What steps can I take to resolve these build errors in Zig?

You should try to use the latest stable release. 0.13 was released on 2024-06-07.

Make sure you download the x86_64 version of zig - the x86 version is broken

ok @pfg, i will use x86_x64 release
